# How do call a framework event with some parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

Can we raise a framework event with some custom parameter. I have a form and children of that form has some context menus. Here the click event for menuitem of that context menu need to holds the information of that form. How do can we get the form name from the menu item click event.

Comment: Hi, how about use attached events? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By using Tag parameter of the framework

Comment: This can also be done but am in search of some generic way like assign a method with different signature to that event..

Comment: if this is correct answer please mark as answer or please share a generic way of usage